# numpy.savetxt resulting a formatting mismatch error in python 3.5

Tags: numpy, formatting, python-3.5

I'm trying to save a numpy matrix (Nx3, float64) into a txt file using numpy.savetxt:

```
np.savetxt(f, mat, fmt='%.5f', delimiter=' ')
```

This line worked in python 2.7, but in python 3.5, I'm getting the following error:

> TypeError: Mismatch between array dtype ('float64') and format
>   specifier ('%.5f %.5f %.5f')

When I'm stepping into the savetxt code, the print the error (traceback.format_exc()) in the catch block (numpy.lib.npyio, line 1158), the error is completely different:

> TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes

The line of code resulting the exception is the following:

```
fh.write(asbytes(format % tuple(row) + newline))
```

I tried to remove the asbytes, and it seems to fix this error. Is it a bug in numpy?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`savetxt` opens the file in `wb` mode, and thus writes everything as bytes.

If instead I open the file with 'w', I get your second error:

```
In [403]: x=np.ones((3,3),dtype=np.float64)
In [404]: with open('test.txt','w') as f:
    np.savetxt(f,x,fmt='%.5f')
   .....:     
TypeError: must be str, not bytes
```

But there's no problem with

```
In [405]: with open('test.txt','wb') as f:
    np.savetxt(f,x,fmt='%.5f')
   .....:     
In [406]: cat test.txt
1.00000 1.00000 1.00000
1.00000 1.00000 1.00000
1.00000 1.00000 1.00000
```

This is on Py3.4; I don't have `numpy` installed with my 3.5 Python.  But I wouldn't expect a difference.

Does

```
'%.5f'%1.2342
```

work on your system? You could also try

```
'%.5f %.5f %.5f'%tuple(mat[0,:])
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked! I'm writing also text to this file, so first I needed to open it with 'w', and then reopen it with 'ab'.

Comment: You can create byte strings with `b'one two three'`.

Comment: I had the same error while writing to a `io.StringIO` object. In that case the solution is to replace it with a `io.BytesIO` object.

Comment: Wow this helped on another issue I had, although I was appending a file `file=open(file, 'ab') mode` and it works with savetext (just added the b)