# numpy.savetxt for 2d array in Python 3.5.1

Tags: numpy, save, python-3.5

my question is related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35372829/numpy-savetxt-resulting-a-formatting-mismatch-error-in-python-3-5) but I can't get that solution to work and didn't want to add my own scenario to the old question.

I have a 2D float numpy array, am running python 3.5.1 with numpy 1.10.4, and am trying to write out the array with

```
numpy.savetext(filename, arrayname, delimiter = ',')
```

which works beautifully with a 1D array.
I've tried the solution from the referenced post

```
with open(filename, 'ab') as f:
    numpy.savetext(f, arrayname, delimiter = ',')
```

to no avail. Actually, I've tried this without the delimiter as well as with 'w', 'wb, 'a'  and with formatting arguments, and always get the same error message:

```
TypeError: Mismatch between array dtype ('float64') and format specifier.
```

I need to write this 2D array to a file which will be read later into a panda dataframe (have been using read.csv). I understand this may be an issue with numpy.savetxt, so I'm looking for an alternative.

Comment: Isn't the command `numpy.savetxt()`?

Comment: Okay, after playing around some more it's now obvious that I actually have a 3d array, not a 2d array, which I need to save to a file that could be read both as an R dataframe (eventually reformatted into long format) or as a numpy array.

Answer (score 2):

Please try a minimal example and post the result, since the following works for me:

```
import numpy as np

array1=np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
np.savetxt('file1.txt', array1 , delimiter = ',')
```

file content:

```
 1.000000000000000000e+00,2.000000000000000000e+00
 3.000000000000000000e+00,4.000000000000000000e+00
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error message - until I finally realized that the type of my output actually was a list, not a numpy array!