# Issue with saving data in files

Tags: arrays, numpy, save

I'm trying to save data in a file.
During my calculations I end up with 3 arrays, Dthick, Dfreq, Dresult.
I want to print them in a file like this

```
Dthick1  Dfreq1 Dresult1
Dthick2  Dfreq2 Dresult2
Dthick3  Dfreq3 Dresult3
Dthick4  Dfreq4 Dresult4
...      ...    ...
```

I tried using this

```
def DATASAVEUR():
 datafile_path = "datafile.txt"
 datafile_id = open(datafile_path, 'wb')    

 with open('datafile.txt','wb') as datafile_id:
     np.savetxt(datafile_id, Dthick,fmt='%.18f',newline='\n')
     np.savetxt(datafile_id, Dfreq,fmt='%.18f',newline='\n')
     np.savetxt(datafile_id, Dresult,fmt='%.18f',newline='\n')

 datafile_id.close()
```

But everything just stay on the same line. 
I tried delimiter and newline
I tried to recombine all data into one array.
But no matter what I do, I end up with something like this

```
Dthick1 Dthick2 Dthick3 ...  Dfreq1 Dfreq2 Dfreq3... Dresult1 Dresult2 Dresult3..
```

The answer must be very simple but I can't seem to find it.

Comment: I think the `newline` argument is used to split arrays that contain multiple rows. Try instead to set `footer='\n'`.

Answer (score 0):

There are two separate issues here:

1. You open the output file in binary mode (the `b` in `wb`), which is not a good idea if you want to write text to the file. Are you using Windows? There the newline character is replaced by a sequence of the Carriage Return and Line Feed characters when you write text, but it's only the Line Feed character in binary mode. Drop the `b` and you will get multiple lines.
2. You are trying to save the first column, then the second column, and then the third column, but saving to a text file proceeds by rows. You can combine the three columns to a two-dimensional matrix and save that instead:

   ```
   np.savetxt("datafile.txt", np.vstack((Dthick,Dfreq,Dresult)).T)
   ```

   Alternatively you could iterate over your three arrays and write them row by row:

   ```
   from itertools import izip
   for thick, freq, result in izip(Dthick, Dfreq, Dresult):
       print >>datafile_id, thick, freq, result
   ```

Comment: Ty for your answer, I dropped the b from wb and I get this error message.
 "Mismatch between array dtype ('float64') and format specifier ('%.18f')"

If I keep the b in order to make the code run, 
np.savetxt("datafile.txt", np.vstack((Dthick,Dfreq,Dresult)).T) 
doesn<t work. I still get the same result.

Comment: What OS are you using, and which version of python? [Python 3 seems to behave differently from Python 2](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35372829/7932936). Are you sure you are getting the same result? I would have expected that you'd get at least "Dthick1 Dfreq1 Dresult1 Dthick2 Dfreq2 Dresult2 ....".  What happens if you leave out the `newline='\n'`?